# How to create sample sale order and sale order line in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to create a sample order in sales order.In the sample order form, products are sold to customers as complimentary copy(books in my case) without charging any money so I have created a separate sub-menu in  sales menu.Here I take only product and quantity as input. Sample order number will be the next number from the sales order(like SO360).So I am fetching sales order number as parent_id in my inherited module.I am not able to create sale order line(data in order lines tab)

[image]
[image]

```py
class SaleOrder(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    # Fields
    is_sample = fields.Boolean(string="Sample Order", default=False)
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string="Parent Sales Order")
    sample_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order', 'parent_id',
                                 string="Sample Orders")

    # Methods
    @api.model
    @api.returns('sale.order')
    def create(self, vals):

        if vals.get('is_sample', False) and vals.get('name', '/') == '/':
            IrSeq = self.env['ir.sequence']
            ref = IrSeq.next_by_code('sale.order.sample.ref') or '/'
            parent = self.search([('id', '=', vals.get('parent_id'))])
            vals['name'] = parent.name + ref
            vals['user_id'] = parent.user_id.id

        return super(SaleOrder, self).create(vals)


class SampleOrderWizard(models.TransientModel):

    _name = 'sale.order.sample.wizard'
    _description = 'Sample Sale Order Wizard'

    # Field default values
    #

    def _get_parent(self):

        res = False
        if self.env.context \
                and 'active_id' in list(self.env.context.iterkeys()):
            res = self.env.context['active_id']

        return res

    def _get_new_sale_line(self, orig_sale, orig_sale_line, wizard_line):
        """Internal function to get the fields of the sale order line. Modules
        enhancing this one should add their own fields to the return value."""

        res = {
            'order_id': orig_sale.id,
            'product_id': orig_sale_line.product_id.id,
            'name': orig_sale_line.name,
            'sequence': orig_sale_line.sequence,
            'price_unit': orig_sale_line.price_unit,
            'product_uom': orig_sale_line.product_uom.id,
            'product_uom_qty': wizard_line and wizard_line.qty or 0,
            'product_uos_qty': wizard_line and wizard_line.qty or 0,
        }

        # Simple check for installation of sale_line_code module
        if hasattr(orig_sale_line, 'order_line_ref'):
            res.update({'order_line_ref': orig_sale_line.order_line_ref})

        return res

    def _get_order_lines(self, sale):

        res = []
        for line in sale.order_line:
            wizard_line = False
            for wzline in self.wizard_lines:
                if wzline.product == line.product_id:
                    wizard_line = wzline
                    break

            if wizard_line:
                res.append(
                    (0, 0, self._get_new_sale_line(sale, line, wizard_line))
                )

        return res

    def _get_wizard_lines(self):

        res = []
        if self._get_parent():
            SaleOrder = self.env['sale.order']
            parent = SaleOrder.search([('id', '=', self._get_parent())])
            for line in parent.order_line:
                res.append((0, 0,
                            {
                                'product': line.product_id,
                                'qty': 1,
                            }))
        return res

    # Fields
    #
    order = fields.Many2one('sale.order', default=_get_parent, readonly=True)
    wizard_lines = fields.One2many('sale.order.sample.wizard.line', 'wizard',
                                   default=_get_wizard_lines)
    order_date = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Datetime.now())

    # Methods
    #

    @api.one
    def create_order(self):

        sale_vals = {
            'user_id': self.order.user_id.id,
            'partner_id': self.order.partner_id.id,
            'parent_id': self.order.id,
            'date_order': self.order_date,
            'client_order_ref': self.order.client_order_ref,
            'company_id': self.order.company_id.id,
            'is_sample': True,
            'order_line': self._get_order_lines(self.order)
        }
        self.env['sale.order'].create(sale_vals)

        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}


class SampleOrderWizardLine(models.TransientModel):

    _name = 'sale.order.sample.wizard.line'
    _description = 'Sample Order Wizard Line'

    wizard = fields.Many2one('sale.order.sample.wizard')
    product = fields.Many2one('product.product',
                              domain=[('sale_ok', '=', True)])
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity", default=1.0,
                       digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product UoS'))
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No error, I am not getting how to create sale order line

Comment: When do you want to fill your new order line?

Comment: once the user press 'create sample order' button